# How does ordering and threading work in TPL DataFlow (Looking for some insight)

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

**Intro**

While working on parallelizing an application for myself I noticed that when an item further in the past takes a long time eventually there will be only one running thread while the rest waits for this item to be completed so that the output can be returned in an ordered fashion.

This all seems fine as I simply commented out the ordered property and my program went full speed ahead.

**My confusion**

What I'm not fully understanding though is where those messages are when they are done with TransformBlock1 but waiting for a previous item to be completed by this block.

In the code I posted here:

https://github.com/devedse/WpfParallelDataflowInvestigation

**Questions**

I've got 3 concrete questions about this code:

1. I've set the bound capacity of this block to 10. But does this bound capacity means that it will store 10 items in some kind of output buffer?
2. It also seems the bounded capacity influences the number of items that can be queued (as can be seen at the start where 10 items get queued).
3. I also log the In: .. and Out: .. buffer counts, but they stay 0 all the time. Where are my messages that are done processing but are waiting to be output untill that item 5 is complete?

**The important code**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ProcessInParallel(IOutputWriter logListener, int maxDegreeOfParallelism = 8)
{
    var theResults = new List<string>();

    var processBlock = new TransformBlock<int, string>(async number =>
    {
        var processedNumber = await ProcessNumber(number);

        return processedNumber;
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism,
        BoundedCapacity = 10
    });

    var putInListBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(t =>
    {

        if (logListener != null)
        {
            logListener.WriteOutput(t);
        }
        theResults.Add(t);
    }, SynchronizeForUiThread(new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {

    }));

    processBlock.LinkTo(putInListBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });


    var ttt = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($">>>>> Threads: {currentThreadsRunning}     In: {processBlock.InputCount} Out: {processBlock.OutputCount}      >>    In: {putInListBlock.InputCount} Out: {putInListBlock.Completion.IsCompleted}");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    });

    var numbers = EnumerateNumberList(100);
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Posting: {number}");
            var result = await processBlock.SendAsync(number);

            if (!result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Result is false!!!");
            }

        }
    });



    Console.WriteLine("Completing");
    processBlock.Complete();
    await putInListBlock.Completion;

    return theResults;
}
```

**Logging**

```
Posting: 0
>>>>> Threads: 0     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
Posting: 1
Posting: 2
Posting: 3
Posting: 4
Posting: 5
Posting: 6
Posting: 7
Posting: 8
Posting: 9
Posting: 10
>>>>> Threads: 8     In: 2 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
>>>>> Threads: 8     In: 2 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
>>>>> Threads: 8     In: 2 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
Processed: 4
>>>>> Threads: 8     In: 1 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
Processed: 7
>>>>> Threads: 8     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
>>>>> Threads: 8     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
Processed: 0
Posting: 11
>>>>> Threads: 8     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
>>>>> Threads: 8     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
Processed: 3
Processed: 9
>>>>> Threads: 6     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
Processed: 8
Processed: 6
Processed: 2
Processed: 1
Posting: 12
Posting: 13
Posting: 14
Posting: 15
>>>>> Threads: 6     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
>>>>> Threads: 6     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
Processed: 10
>>>>> Threads: 5     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
>>>>> Threads: 5     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
>>>>> Threads: 5     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
Processed: 13
>>>>> Threads: 4     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
>>>>> Threads: 4     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
Processed: 11
Processed: 14
>>>>> Threads: 2     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
Processed: 12
>>>>> Threads: 1     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
>>>>> Threads: 1     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
>>>>> Threads: 1     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
>>>>> Threads: 1     In: 0 Out: 0      >>    In: 0 Out: False
```

Comment: In short yes the `BoundedCapacity` sets both the Input and Output buffer capacity. It doesn't look like anything significant is being done in the example so it may just be that the buffers are empty.

Comment: Also your `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` will affect how many items can processed concurrently regardless of buffer size (to an extent)

Comment: Ok I understand that :), but the items that have not been processed by the 'putInListBlock' do still exist somewhere. (They are waiting to be output in an ordered manner). But I can't find any property on either of those blocks that contains an integer with a value of 9 or 10 items are done but waiting to be output to the next block as we have not received a previous result.

Comment: OK just so we're on the same page: you want the items processed in parallel and ordered, item 1 is slow, item 2-10 are fast. In that case those fast items will enter an internal re-ording buffer that holds the items untill all are ready to move along. It's been a while since I pulled up the source code but I'll take a look.

Comment: And [here it is](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Internal/ReorderingBuffer.cs) you can dig around more to see exactly how it's used.

Comment: Ah yeah makes sense, but is there a way to see how much items are in this buffer?

Comment: I don't think so, not anything publicly exposed at least. You could use reflection to get a count out though.